# Why plug in 0? Using MGF to prove E[X] =1

Tags: probability

I just don't get why we plug in 0 into the variable t after we find the derivative. I would appreciate an explanation of some sort. Thanks in advance!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the series expansion $$e^z = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}.$$  Then with $z = tX$, we see that $$\operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(tX)^k}{k!}\right].$$  By the linearity of expectation (and under the assumption that the moments exist), we then have $$\psi_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{E}[X^k]}{k!} t^k,$$ and by Taylor's theorem, this is equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\psi_X^{(k)}(0)}{k!} t^k.$$  Equating like terms gives $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \psi_X^{(k)}(0) = \frac{d^k}{dt^k} \left[ \psi_X(t) \right]_{t=0};$$ that is to say, the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moment of $X$ is equal to the $k^{\rm th}$ derivative of the MGF of $X$ evaluated at $0$.